# JQuery Prepending text in front of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have a unordered list with links and sublinks. I'd like to prepend a `'»'` character in front of the sublinks in the list. I could probably do this with CSS via `list-style-image:url` but I'd rather just have text. So far I have tried prepend without much success.

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">sublink link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublink link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And I am using this code:

```
 $("ul li li").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').prepend("»").html();
   });
```

If I take away one level of list items and prepend to all list items, then it works but viewing in web inspector, the `»` character still has quotes around it. I also tried various incarnations of what appeared for closest such as `li a` but that did not make a difference either. I'm not getting any syntax errors so not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have a [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/highrockmedia/E9gSV/3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not some css?

```
ul ul li:before {
 content: '»';   
}
```

Using JavaScript to modify the UI for something like this is a waste of resources. This is subjective without knowing your actual use case.

Comment: I like this, I only need it for mobile devices anyway so no worries about the CSS not working in certain browsers. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted because you helped me think outside the box, it works and it does not use unnecessary resources.

Comment: @DannyEnglander glad I could help, my perspective was merely pragmatic, you are modifying the view only and css is built for it.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is not correct, also there is no need to use `html` and `each` methods.

```
$("ul ul li").prepend("»");
```

Comment: Elegant and simple, I like it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You had an incorrect selector `ul li li` implied there was an `li` directly within an `li` but there is another `ul` between.

In addition you don't need to use a `.each` for that as jQuery will return the reference to the set of elements which matched the selector.

```
$("ul ul li").prepend("»");
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/E9gSV/10/)

Mind you the CSS solution from `Aknosis` looks very cool.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are needing:

```
 $("ul ul li").prepend("» ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $("ul li").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend("»").html();
 });
```